# C# char "//" path separator

Tags: c#, separator

Is there possible to use char "//" another there I did it? I looked for in Path, but I can't find it.

```
  string separator = "//";
```

I mean '/'.

I used:

```
static string sep = System.IO.Path.PathSeparator.ToString();
```

but it returns: ';'. Why?

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't clear. A shot in the dark, but are you looking for `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx

Comment: Why two slashes instead of one?

Comment: Well you have to use two slashes, or @"/"

Comment: No, only a "\\" needs to be escaped, not a "/".

Comment: @Ani Wrong. `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` contains '/' on Windows and '\' on UNIX. You must use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is [`System.IO.Path.PathSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.pathseparator.aspx) what you're actually looking for? There's also [`.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) and others. See the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class under "Fields".

To elaborate, a path separator is used to concatenate multiple full paths together (think the `PATH` environmental variable). It sounds like you're after the directory separator, which is used within a single path to split out folders/ files. (In windows it's commonly `\`, and `/` basically elsewhere).

Answer (score 77):

`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` gives you the character used to separate **directories** in a path, i.e. you use it **in** paths.

`Path.PathSeparator` gives you the character used to separate **paths** in environment variables, i.e. you use it **between** paths.

For example, your system's `PATH` environment variable will typically list multiple paths where the OS will look for applications to run.

On Windows, `Path.PathSeparator` is `;`, and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is `\`. Two paths would be stored in an environment variable like this:

```
set PATH="C:\first\path;C:\second\path"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's read only, you can't change it. A Path represents a path that the operating system running the framework and your application understands. If you use any other value, the OS won't understand it. There's no OS in the world which understands "a//b//c" paths. But you can have arbitrary strings which contain paths like that, except they won't be OS-understandable file paths, and you can call them something else.

Comment: OSs that understand / as path separator, ignore the second /, so a//b//c is same as a/b/c. I tried on Windows Vista (in Cygwin) and Apple OS X 10.6.5. The both understand a//b//c as a/b/c.

Answer (score 0):

For Forward slash '/' use Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar .
you can check full list here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-7.0

Answer (score -3):

It's equal to [`Path.PathSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.pathseparator.aspx), it's better to use this,